# TSQL nested basic query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, subquery

I am stuck to a T-SQL query. I think that it is basic. But I coundn't figure it out. Can someone be kind enough to shed some light on it? Thanks in advance!

Here is my question. I want to write a query to do the following tasks:

Raw Data:

```
Department Type Salary Age 
1 1 1000 30 
1 2 1500 31 
1 3 2000 25 
2 1 250 35 
2 2 50 20 
2 3 300 35
```

Ideally, I want to have a table, which have the following info:

```
Department Type Salary Age
1 3 2000 25
1 2 1500 31
1 1 1000 30
2 3 300 35
2 1 250 35
```

The selection is based on a comparison in each Department. I compare the Salary of each Type within each Department. And the ones whose Salary is larger than or equal to Type 1 in the same Department will be selected. Then within each Department, the records are ordered in a descending order on Salary.

Here is my wrong codes.

```
SELECT Department, Type, Salary, Age
FROM Database.dbo.Table1
WHERE Salary >=  
(
SELECT Salary
FROM Database.dbo.Table1
WHERE Type = 1
GROUP BY Department
)
GROUP BY Department
```

I hope the illustration is clear. Please feel free to let me know if it is not. I can explain more.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing too tricky here - just a self-join back to the same table to identify the `Type = 1` Salary and then a fairly normal `ORDER BY` clause:

Sample data:

```
declare @t table (Department int,[Type] int, Salary int, Age int)
insert into @t(Department,[Type], Salary, Age ) values
(1 ,1 ,1000 ,30    ),
(1 ,2 ,1500 ,31    ),
(1 ,3 ,2000 ,25    ),
(2 ,1 ,250 ,35     ),
(2 ,2 ,50 ,20      ),
(2 ,3 ,300 ,35     )
```

Query:

```
select
    t1.*
from
    @t t1
        inner join
    @t t2
        on
            t1.Department = t2.Department and
            t1.Salary >= t2.Salary and
            t2.[Type] = 1
order by t1.Department, t1.Salary desc
```

You're attempt to use `GROUP BY` was wrong because `GROUP BY` doesn't have any effect<sup>1</sup> on the final output order.

---

<sup>1</sup> As a *side effect* of the way that grouping is processed, the output *may* be sorted in an order that is useful to you - but that's only a side effect and not guaranteed. The only way to guarantee ordering is with an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Hi Damien, thanks for help! Actually, the support is so quick that I got goose bumps... I tried your code, and it is working! However, can you explain a little bit about the @t ? I see the @ little mouse/rose/hat sign a lot, but don't quite understand it...

Comment: @LinguisticsStudent - `@t` was the name I gave to a table-variable (most variables in T-SQL start with a `@`). A table variable is convenient for writing quick, throwaway code for answers to questions here, because it disappears once the SQL has run - I don't have to clean up after writing this script. (They do also have other uses). See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Hi Damien, thanks for the explanation! I searched the key word a little bit. Another question is, I actually use a view, rather than table in my work. And it is weird enough to not work... Is it because that it is a view? Or do you have other suggestion? I think there is no typo. The code is executed, but with 0 rows affected.

Comment: @LinguisticsStudent - views should, for most intents and purposes, be indistinguishable from tables. If you're getting 0 rows, then probably one or more of the conditions in the `on` clause is incorrect. You can try experimenting with removing one or more of the conditions (also, temporarily, replace `t1.*` with just `*`) until you start seeing results, and then work out why the results are being filtered out.

Comment: Hi @Damien_The_Unbeliever, it works! Thanks again!! I find the error. Put a wrong variable in my code...

Comment: Be careful with using ORDER BY in a view. I know that in most scenarios an ORDER BY is not supported in VIEWS. Try to apply the ORDER BY once you select from your view. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms187956(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: @BorhanMooz - I took the OPs comments to mean that they were selecting from a view, not that this query was to be placed in a view. But if so, yes, worth having that warning.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever That's right. That was meant more as a guide for the OP since using this query in a VIEW was mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Hi@Damien_The_Unbeliever,@BorhanMooz, it is true that I am creating a view for the new table, and I do need the order by to sort the list. I read the page that @BorhanMooz has quoted. It says, "The ORDER BY clause is used only to determine the rows that are returned by the TOP clause in the view definition. The ORDER BY clause does not guarantee ordered results when the view is queried, unless ORDER BY is also specified in the query itself." I am not quite understanding the last part. Can you explain a little bit?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, by the way, the ORDER BY seems working in my test for the view in my situation. Is it a good sign or just a coincidence @BorhanMooz?

Comment: @LinguisticsStudent - the only `ORDER BY` clause that guarantees the order of the results that are returned is the one on the outermost query that you submit to the server - any other `ORDER BY` clause (inside views, in subqueries, CTEs, etc), is only meant to determine *which* rows are selected (via a `TOP`), *not* the order of the result set.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, THANKS SO MUCH for you explanation! You are the best! I got a better understanding for this. For future reference, here is another link to explain `ORDER BY` clause: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from T as t1
where 
type=1
or
Exists(select 1 from t where t.[Department]=t1.[Department]
                             and
                             t.type=1
                             and 
                             salary<t1.salary 
                             )

order by [Department],salary DESC
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fbe38/4)

Comment: Hi Valex, thanks for the help! I appreciate it! I am sure the code is correct since it is working in the Fiddle. However, I must have done something stupid, and ran into the same problem I had for Damien's suggestion. Is it because I use a view rather than the table?